# Kotlin Serialiazation with polymorphism MissingFieldException

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, kotlinx.serialization

I have these Model classes

```
@Serializable
open class BaseModel(

    var network: String? = null,
    var type: String? = null,

    var createdOn: String? = null,
    var updatedOn: String? = null,

    var name: String? = null,
    var imageUrl: String? = null,
    var description: String? = null,

    var validity: String? = null
)

@Serializable
open class BundleOffer(

    var sms: String? = null,
    var onNet: String? = null,
    var offNet: String? = null,
    var internet: String? = null

    ) : BaseModel()
```

now these classes define in `kotlin-jvm` module and i need to create child type for framework-specific use case so i have created test for that like that

```
    @Serializable
    class BundleOfferChildType(val isFavourite: Boolean = false) : BundleOffer()

    @Test
    fun decodeArrayOfBundleOfferAsChildType() {

        val jsonString = javaClass.classLoader
            .getResourceAsStream("test_bundles_offers_data.json")!!
            .readBytes().toString(Charsets.UTF_8)

        val json = Json {
            encodeDefaults = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        }

        val result =
            json.decodeFromString(ListSerializer(BundleOfferChildType.serializer()), jsonString)

        assertThat(result.size).isEqualTo(2)
    }
```

i have `test_bundles_offers.json` file data as below but there is no `createdOn`,`updatedOn` in data and giving MissingFieldException for them but these should be ignored or should be assigned default value as defined in Json configuration

```
[    
  {
    "network": "...",
    "type": "...",
    "name": "Bundle offer 1",
    "imageUrl": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "validity": "...",
    "sms": "...",
    "offNet": "...",
    "onNet": "...",
    "internet": "..."
   },
     {
    "network": "...",
    "type": "...",
    "name": "Bundle offer 2",
    "imageUrl": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "validity": "...",
    "sms": "...",
    "offNet": "...",
    "onNet": "...",
    "internet": "..."
   }
]
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, works fine for me (with kotlinx.serialization 1.2.2)

Comment: yeah that's the problem some times it works for some classes and sometimes it won't its wired

Comment: see this i getting error https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifJsW.png

Comment: I mean it works for me with the provided classes and JSON. Could you share a [minimal, complete & reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Ideally, in a form of a GitHub project, utilizing some build system, so that this error could be reproduced with a `gradle test`/`mvn test` command.

Comment: try [this](https://github.com/burhankhanzada/KotlinX-Serialization-polymorphism-bug-sample) and run `decodeArrayOfBundleOfferAsChildType` in `test/JsonSerializationTest`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the fact that `BundleOfferChildType` class was declared in the `test` source set, so the plugin-generated serializer is erroneous (specifically, its descriptor; it's implemented as an instance of the internal `PluginGeneratedSerialDescriptor` class, and for some reason, in this case, its private `elementsOptionality` field is filled with `false` values; it would have been correctly filled with `true` if `BundleOfferChildType`class was declared in the `main` source set).

I believe it's a bug of `kotlinx.serialization`.

As a workaround, just move `BundleOfferChildType` class from `test` to the `main` source set.

Comment: well main be your right about BundleOfferChildType bee in test source test making this wired behaviour but after your answer i ahve reopen the sample project and just removed BundleOfferChildType  and just run that test again and now its showing `BundleOffer` to missing Feilds but i ahve checked its decomplied bytecode and all of that feilds are optional see [this] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfbTa.png)

Comment: now it confirmed that a bug can u file a bug because i don't know if i give that sample to as sample they can reproduce it nor not and i don't have enough knowledge of kotlinx serialization to define that bug properly

Comment: Try to run the `gradle clean` task before rerunning test. Bug with `BundleOffer` is still reproducible?

Comment: Looks like this (or a similar one) bug is already reported: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1602

Comment: downgrading kotlin version to `1.5.10` does fix wired behaviour that some times its works and some times it doesn't but still if I have `A` serializable class and a `B` class extend from `A` in `main` source and then use it to extend class `C` from `B` in `test` source of in another `module` its till giving error `missing optional field`